# How to create custom Webhook - Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, webhooks

We will integrate with a partner via webhooks and our project is in .NET Core 3.1.

Does anyone have an example of how we can create a url receiver to integrate with this webhook? In the links from Microsoft I saw an example only with Azure, but not with a custom one. Would anyone have any help?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/master/src/WebHooks Under development.